# ColdFusion query of query date comparison

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query created from using `cfspreadsheet` that has a date column named "Actiondate", and looping through the query using `isDate()` shows that it's a date column, but in a query of that query it is being treated as a string. So when I apply a date filter in the where clause, it doesn't do the comparison correctly:

```
<cfquery ... >
SELECT *
FROM arguments.q
WHERE 1=1
<cfif isDate(arguments.dateFrom)>
    AND actiondate >= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#arguments.dateFrom#">
</cfif>
<cfif isDate(arguments.dateFrom)>
    AND actiondate <= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#arguments.dateTo#">
</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

`actiondate` comes in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`. When I do the where clause using  string literals as a test, it works:

```
...where actiondate = '11/05/2015' --returns all rows with that "date"

<cfset tempdate = createdate(2015,11,5)>...
...where actiondate = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#temp#"> --returns nothing
```

But again, `isDate(actiondate)` returns true when looping through the query. I can work around the problem, but is there a way to do what I need to still using a query of query?

Comment: You realize that both of your cfifs check the same value?

Comment: Wrap the parameter in quotes: `'<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#arguments.dateFrom#">'`. Does that work?

Comment: @trincot, did you try that yourself?  Did you get the expected results?

Comment: It's hard to say if you can do what you need to do with Q of Q because it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk  - Trying to filter out all rows from the query that aren't in the date range. If it can't be done using q of q in one step, I'll loop through the query using cfif, build a list of all row ids that satisfy the date comparison, and then use that list in the where clause of the q of q.

Comment: `IsDate` verifies a value *can* be converted into a date. It does not mean that value already *is* a datetime value. In the case of cfspreadsheet, the returned query values are strings. When you try and compare the strings to the cfqueryparam values (ie datetime objects) the QoQ does an implicit conversion to string and comes up with the wrong answer. To perform a date comparison on them via a QoQ, you must use `CAST` and convert them into a date/time objects.

Comment: ie Assuming all of the values are valid date strings in the format mm/dd/yyyy, try this a hard coded value first: `WHERE  CAST(actionDate AS DATE) = <cfqueryparam value="11/05/2015" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">`. Then plug in your variables.

Comment: @Leigh Ah yes, there it is, thank you. I thought about CAST(), but didn't try it because A) I thought isDate() confirms the datatype (which the cf documentation would have told me is incorrect if I'd bothered to check), and B) most SQL functions aren't available in a q of q.

Comment: (Edit) @Cmaso - Yes, it is one of the [half dozen or so functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html) actually supported in QoQ's ;-) If that fixed it, I will write up answer to close out the thread.

Comment: @Leigh That fixed it - thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

(From comments ...)

`IsDate` verifies a value *can* be converted into a date. That does not mean the value already *is* a date/time object. In the case of cfspreadsheet, the returned query values are strings. When you compare them to the cfqueryparam values, which are date/time objects, you are comparing apples and oranges. So the QoQ does an implicit conversion of the date/time values to string and comes up with the wrong answer.

To perform a date comparison on "ActionDate", you must use [CAST](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html) to convert the strings into a date/time objects first.  Assuming all of the values are valid date strings, in the format mm/dd/yyyy, try it with a hard coded value like 11/05/2015 first. Then plug in your variables.

```
WHERE CAST(actionDate AS DATE) = <cfqueryparam value="11/05/2015" 
                                     cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
```